# Finding and Destroying Tiles of the same color in Java Game Project

Tags: java, arrays

I would like you to help me as i am a student and i have been having trouble with my project. The project is a game called Brick Breaker.

In the game i have to create a panel of bricks that are basically jButtons that when clicked will check the neighboring buttons of the same color and if there are 2 or more with the same color jthey will be destroyed and then the other bricks will have to collapse and get in their place is the row is empty or come closer if the column is empty.

What i have done till now is that i created the frame and the panel with the coloured bricks in a 2d array but i tried to use an action listener on the buttons and failed.

Also i am not able to find all the neighboring buttons with the same color.
I am unable to upload a picture as i am new to the forum any help would be appreciated.

This is a link with the game i am trying to make in java
 http://el.y8.com/games/easy_brick

I apologize for the long post.

I added the code as requested.
Note: I am not experienced with Java Programming and I know i can improve my code but i lack the experience I am just getting starting.

```
public class BB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size=14;
        BB neighbours = new BB();
        JButton button[][]=new JButton[size][size];        
        ActionListener listener=(ActionEvent ae) -> {
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){    //creating an array holding buttons and randomly coloring them
                for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                    if (ae.getSource()==button[i][j]){
                        neighbours.checkup(button,i,j);
                        neighbours.checkdown(button,i,j);
                        neighbours.checkleft(button,i,j);
                        neighbours.checkright(button,i,j);
                        break;}
                }
            }
        };
        Random rand = new Random();
        JFrame frame =new JFrame("BrickBreaker");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){    //creating an array holding buttons and randomly coloring them
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                button[i][j]= new JButton();
                button[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
            int x=rand.nextInt(4);
           switch (x) {
               case 0:
                   button[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE); 
                   break;
               case 1:
                   button[i][j].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA); 
                   break;
               case 2:
                   button[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
                   break;
               case 3:
                   button[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
                   break;
               default:
                   button[i][j].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA); 
                   break;
           }
            panel.add(button[i][j]);
        }}
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(900,900);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void checkup(JButton[][] button,int i, int j){
        if(button[i][j].getBackground()==button[i][j-1].getBackground() && j-1>0){
            if(button[i][j]!=null)
                button[i][j]=null;
            checkleft(button,i,j-1);
            checkright(button,i,j-1);
            checkup(button,i,j-1);}
    }

    public void checkdown(JButton[][] button, int i, int j){
        if(button[i][j].getBackground()==button[i][j+1].getBackground() && j+1<14){
            if(button[i][j]!=null)
                button[i][j]=null;
            checkleft(button,i,j+1);
            checkright(button,i,j+1);
            checkdown(button,i,j+1);}
    }

    public void checkleft(JButton[][] button, int i, int j){
        if(button[i][j].getBackground()==button[i-1][j].getBackground() && i-1>0){
            if(button[i][j]!=null)
                button[i][j]=null;
            checkup(button,i-1,j);
            checkdown(button,i-1,j);
            checkleft(button,i-1,j);}
    }
    public void checkright(JButton[][] button, int i, int j){
        if(button[i][j].getBackground()==button[i+1][j].getBackground() && i+1<14){
            if(button[i][j]!=null)
                button[i][j]=null;
            checkup(button,i+1,j);
            checkdown(button,i+1,j);
            checkright(button,i+1,j);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you failed, we're not going to write the program for you.

Comment: consider using stacked flowlayouts that contain your buttons. by deleting one button the layout will take care of squishing the remaining buttons together . you use 1 flow layout for each row, stack them horizontally, add the buttons to the flow layout. if you make it vanish layout will do most work. dont reinvent the wheel - unless you need a 9sided one.

Comment: @TreytenCarey I have uploaded the code any change or proposal or even new code would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Your idea is really smart. Will this affect the size of the buttons ? Will the buttons come down vertically when i delete a group of bricks with the same color? Sorry if my questions sound stupid.

Comment: does not sound stupid - you could use one single flow layout. if will break to next row if current row overflows. kindof difficult to know which buttons are below/above you though...